# OpenLDAP ACL's in SUSE, Kerberos configuration

Tags: openldap, kerberos, opensuse, sles

I'm implementing Kerberos with OpenLDAP manually and according to the [MIT Documentation](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/admin/conf_ldap.html), I've to set manually this ACL:

```
access to dn.base=""
    by * read

access to dn.base="cn=Subschema"
    by * read

# Provide access to the realm container.
access to dn.subtree= "cn=EXAMPLE.COM,cn=krbcontainer,dc=example,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=kdc-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by dn.exact="cn=adm-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by * none

# Provide access to principals, if not underneath the realm container.
access to dn.subtree= "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=kdc-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by dn.exact="cn=adm-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by * none

access to *
    by * read
```

According to what I read, I've to set that in slapd.conf.

I think Suse does not use slapd.conf so I'm figuring out how should I add these entries. I'm totally stucked.

Could anybody help me?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent versions of OpenLDAP use LDAP itself to maintain its configuration. Everything is contained in the [cn=config subtree](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html) in a database called `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`. Access to this database is usually given to the local user **root** on the machine.

In order to modify the configuration you have first to find your main database name:

```
ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(objectClass=olcDatabaseConfig)'
```

where the SASL EXTERNAL method checks the uid and gid of the user running the command (so you must be **root**).

Once you found your database name (let's say `dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config`) you need to create a file (let's say `authz.ldif`) in LDIF format:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: to dn.base=""
    by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="cn=Subschema"
    by * read
olcAccess: to dn.subtree= "cn=EXAMPLE.COM,cn=krbcontainer,dc=example,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=kdc-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by dn.exact="cn=adm-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by * none
olcAccess: to dn.subtree= "ou=users,dc=example,dc=com"
    by dn.exact="cn=kdc-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by dn.exact="cn=adm-service,dc=example,dc=com" write
    by * none
olcAccess: to *
    by * read
```

This will replace all your previous `olcAccess` attributes with the new ones. Then you need to send the update to the OpenLDAP server:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f authz.ldif
```

Remark: On your LDAP server you usually want to access the server through the URI `ldapi:///` (i.e. a UNIX socket), so you can add:

```
URI ldapi:///
```

to your `ldap.conf` file (`man 5 ldap.conf`), which has different paths on different distributions. E.g. on Debian it is in `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf`.

Comment: You saved my life, thank you so much.